# How to compare objects in array RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to compare objects with the same parameter in ruby? How to define `elsif` part?

```
def compare
    array_of_items = @items.map(&:object_id)
    if array_of_items.uniq.size == array_of_items.size #array has only uniq vlaues - it's not possible to duplicate object - good!
      return
    elsif
      #the comparision of objects with the same object_id by other param (i.e. date_of_lease param). The part I can not formulate
    else
      errors.add('It is not possible to purchase many times one item with the same values')
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do you want to count the number of duplicate objects in an array?

Comment: Jayaprakash I wan't to compare objects with the same parameter (object_id) with other param: If array of items has two objects with the same one param (object_id) i want to compare it by other param

Comment: `array_of_items - array_of_items.uniq = object(s) has same object_id` and then you compare the object(s) with others param

Comment: `Object#object_id` already returns unique value, there is no chances to get duplicates there. You are free to compare exclusively by other parameter.

Comment: Instead of downvoting everyone's answers you should give feedback as to why they don't work for you

Comment: _"comparision of objects with the same object_id by other param"_ doesn't make much sense. Same object id means that these are the same objects. Their attributes will of course be identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable#group_by`, e.g.

```
elsif @items.group_by(&:date_of_lease).count == array_of_items.size
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, I guess you want to compare two objects with same object_id.

```
same_objects = @items.select { | element |
        if array_of_items.count(element.object_id) > 1 do 
           # Duplicate object
        end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how about other Ruby implementations, but in MRI `Object#object_id` returns **unique** (integer representation of the object in memory) value for every object. If you try to redefine it, you will get the warning:

```
class Object
  def object_id
    'a'
  end
end
#=> warning: redefining `object_id' may cause serious problems
:object_id
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since this is tagged as rails, isn't this the type of thing you can solve with a built in validation?

```
 validates_uniqueness_of :date_of_lease, scope: :object_id
```

I don't know know about your implementation, but if you used the primary key of your database you might not even need that scope.

Otherwise, assuming you have overriden ruby `object_id` so two objects can have the same ids (¿?) I can only think of something complex like:

```
 def compare
   duplicate_items = @items.group_by(&:object_id).select { |k,v| v.size > 1}
   if duplicate_items.keys.empty? 
     return
   elsif duplicate_items.select{|k,v| v.group_by(&:date_of_lease).count != v.count}.empty?
     # There are no duplicate object ids that also have duplicate 
     # dates of lease between themselves
   else
      errors.add('It is not possible to purchase many times one item with the same values')
   end
 end
```

Check that you have to handle the case where there are different object ids with the same date of lease in the same `items` array that has duplicates, that should be valid. For example : `Item id 1, date 12, Item id 1, date 13, item id 2, date 12` Should be valid.